# how do i get FireFox to respond to jquery .click event properly?

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

I have an event listener set up for the click event that moves a div to a new location.  The div starts out a left value of 100. After the click the "left" value changes to 300 but the div is still in the same place on the screen. In Chrome and IE it actually moves to the new location. How do I get the same thing from FireFox? I can see that the event was fired. The alert box shows the position as 300, but the div didn't change places on the screen.

```
$(menu_button_wrapper).click(function() {
    $(home).css({
        'left': 300
    })
});
var temp = $(home).position();
alert(temp.left);
```

Edit to add HTML:

```
<div id="menu_button_wrapper">
<table id="menu_button" cellpadding=5 cellmargin=0>
 <tr>
  <td align=center>
    &nbsp;Menu &nbsp;
  </td>
  <td align=center>
   <img src="elephant.png" width=50>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Is menu_button_wrapper a variable containing the class name? If not, you should remember that in jQuery, within the $() you should have the CSS selector as a string. For example, I'm guessing you want `$('.menu_button_wrapper')` instead of `$(menu_button_wrapper)`. As for why it works in IE and Chrome, maybe they can understand what you mean but Firefox needs you to be explicit.

Comment: $(menu_button_wrapper) is a div ID. It works for everything else I am doing, so I don't think that is it.

Comment: @user2721815 when targeting id you should use `$('#menu_button_wrapper')`

Answer (score 1):

Check it here https://jsfiddle.net/3hkqbt32/

I just used different selectors for testing purpose like this:

```
$('button').click( function() {$('.home').css({'left':300})} );
var temp = $(home).position();
alert(temp.left);
```

For me it works fine in Firefox also. Does it work for you?

Also, when you target id in jQuery you should use this syntax: `$('#menu_button_wrapper')`

**Edit**

Instead of using `left:300` use `margin-left`.
For some reason Firefox doesn't get it like other browsers on your web.

Comment: I pasted your code into my page and I see the alert shows that the div's left value is 300 just like before. but the div doesn't move. It's like the screen isn't updating or something. This is madness! It works fine everywhere but FF.

Comment: then something is wrong with your ff.. what version do you use? did you tried to restart it? do you see some errors in ff console?

Comment: There are no errors in the console. I am using the latest version. It does work in the fiddle. FF ver 46.0.1

Comment: ok so problem is in your code.. make jsfiddle with your full code and give it here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111365/discussion-between-user2721815-and-jakob).